# SQL Location Query

Tags: error-handling, google-bigquery, location

In creating a create model I got an error that states my dataset is not found in location. How do I go about fixing this? I do not understand why it gave an error.... everything else looks to be correct. I tried searching the error but need someone to help walk me through what I should do to fix it. Step by step instruction would be great!

Answer (score 0):

Can you post the exact error message and example query?

One possibility is you are not providing the fully qualified table name inclusive of project.  By default BigQuery will look in the project you are currently utilizing so if  the table you are querying exists in another project you'll receive a message like:

`Not found: Dataset [DEFAULT PROJECT]:[DATASET FROM ANOTHER PROJECT] was not found in location US`